# Groovy/Grails: How to compose closures without breaking DSL

Tags: grails, groovy, closures, dsl

I'm wondering how to **call a closure from a closure that's being used with a DSL**.  For example, let's take the `RestBuilder` plugin for Grails.

Imagine I have several blocks in a row like:

```
rest.post("http://my.domain/url") {
    auth(username, password)
    contentType "text/xml"
    body someContent
}
```

... where the only thing changing is the `someContent`. It gets repetitive to call `auth` and `contentType` and `body` each time.  So I'd like to do something like:

```
def oauth = [clientId: 'c', clientSecret: 's']

def withAuth(Closure toWrap) {
    Closure wrapped = { it ->
        auth(oauth.clientId, oauth.clientSecret)
        contentType "text/xml"
        toWrap.call()
    }
    return wrapped
}

rest.post("http://my.domain/url") (withAuth {
    body someContent
})
```

Now, I'd like `wrapped` and `toWrap` to have access to `auth` and `contentType` as defined in the `RestBuilder` DSL.  Is there a way I can do this by setting owners, delegates, or suchlike?

(Note: I understand in the example above that I could just declare a function that takes a URL + content as argument, and just call `rest.post` within the function. My question is more general -- I'm looking to understand the language, and for functional techniques I can apply more broadly.)

Comment: probably setting `delegate` will be enough: `toWrap.delegate = delegate; toWrap.call()`

Comment: That doesn't quite do the trick, because when it's called, the code in `wrapped` can't see oauth in the top scope.

Comment: Ah, I see I need to define `oauth` as a @Field in my script (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305910/how-do-we-create-and-access-the-global-variables-in-groovy)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @igor-artamonov, I have the following working approach.  Note that I changed `withAuth` from a function to a closure so that it could access script-level state without having to declare `@Field` variables on the script.

```
def oauth = [clientId: 'c', clientSecret: 's']

def withAuth { Closure toWrap ->
   return { 
      auth(oauth.clientId, oauth.clientSecret)
      contentType "text/xml"
      toWrap.delegate = delegate
      toWrap.call()
   }
}

rest.post("http://my.domain/url", withAuth {
    body someContent
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the fact that the syntax there of `foo(params) { ... }` is syntactic sugar for `foo(params, { ... })`:

```
def c = { oauth, b ->
   auth(oauth.clientId, oauth.clientSecret)
   contentType "text/xml"
   body b
}

...

def doPost(String body) {
   rest.post("http://my.domain/url", c.clone().curry(oauth, body))
}
```

Cloning the closure each time prevents stale state, and currying the values caches them in the closure so they're available when it's invoked by the Rest builder.

Comment: This is a great bit of syntax to know, but it doesn't quite get at the question of how I can compose closures:  in this case, you're passing a single closure to `rest.post` (and that closure, returned by `curry`, doesn't run any closures inside).