# Script working in online editor but not in java GroovShell (No such property)

Tags: java, groovy

I'm working for the first time with `Groovy`. I have a simple script, that I want to run on my Java server.

I build the script here [MyScript in the Groovy web console](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5095816964341760), and when I run it, it returns what I expect `[1,10]`.

```
minValue=1;
maxValue=10;
listValues=[];
enumMap=[];
rangeType="RANGE"; //RANGE,LIST,ENUM,NONE


Object test(int arg){
    return getRange();
}


Object[] getRange(){
    if (rangeType=="NONE"){
        return [];
    }

    if (rangeType=="RANGE"){
        return [minValue,maxValue];
    }

    if (rangeType=="LIST"){
        return listValues;
    }

    if (rangeType=="ENUM"){
        return enumMap;
    }
}

println(test(1));
```

On my Java server I invoke the `test` method this way

```
Script groovyScript = new GroovyShell().parse(script);
return groovyScript.invokeMethod("test", valueSuccess);
```

Although the script runs fine in the web console, when I run it on my server it gives me the following exception:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: rangeType for class: Script1
```

The exact same script once runs without a problem, once it throws an exception. How can that be? It's not even complex, and the variable declarations should be correct, aren't they?

Comment: have you tried `def rangeType="RANGE"; //RANGE,LIST,ENUM,NONE`?

Comment: Please give some `Data type` for the `variable` rangeType like `String` or `def`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like you to `import` the `field annotation` package and correct the decalartion of variables.Specify some `datatype` for them along with the `@Field annotation` to access the variable anywhere in the script.

```
import groovy.transform.Field

@Field int minValue   = 1;
@Field int maxValue   = 10;
@Field List listValues= [];
@Field Map enumMap    = [:];
@Field def rangeType  = "RANGE"; //RANGE,LIST,ENUM,NONE
```

reference link for [creating and accessing the global variables in Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305910/how-do-i-create-and-access-the-global-variables-in-groovy)

Comment: If he does that, it will not work anywhere. By defining them as he does, they are global variables within the script. Thus they are visible by the `getRange()` method. If he were to do as you ask, then none of these would be visible within the method and the script would fail.

Comment: @BalRog.Good find.I have found a workaround for the same and added to the answer.

Comment: @AbhinandanSatpute Thanks, that did the trick!
there are just to many ways to define a variable in groovy...