# Why groovy doesn't print a globally defined variable?

Tags: groovy

Here defined `a` doesn't print inside an method `doit()`.

```
Integer a =0

void doit ()
{
    println a
}
```

May be i am stupid to ask it. Whats happening here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make scope available for given method as follows,

```
import groovy.transform.Field
@Field Integer a = 1
void doit () { 
println a
}

doit ()​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Read more : [How do I create and access the global variables in Groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305910/how-do-i-create-and-access-the-global-variables-in-groovy)