# Jenkins groovy (SharedLibrary) class can't access WorkflowScript members

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, workflowscript, cps

I have a simple pipeline script that access a groovy class (which resides in a shared library),
the pipeline script pass a reference (to itself) to the class,
the class then calls a function or a closure found in the script,
that function access a member in that same script,

the result is a groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException exception.

so here is the actual (runnable) code:

> **Jenkins pipeline script:**

```
@Library("testLib") _

import my.domain.Tester;

public Tester tester = new Tester(this);

def closure()
{
    echo "tester: " + tester;
}

node("master")
{
    tester.test();
}
```

> **com.domain.Tester.groovy class:**

```
package my.domain

class Tester
{
    Script scriptRef = null;

    public Tester(Script scriptRef)
    {
        this.scriptRef = scriptRef;
    }

    public void test()
    {
        this.scriptRef.closure();
    }
}
```

> **the exception received:**

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: tester for class: WorkflowScript
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.getProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:458)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.getProperty(DefaultInvoker.java:39)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at WorkflowScript.closure(WorkflowScript:9)
    at my.domain.Tester.test(Tester.groovy:8)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:23)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor538.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:186)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:370)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:93)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:282)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:270)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Finished: FAILURE
```

so obviously it is something happening due to the ***cps transform*** procedure the pipeline script goes through, and the script member is not there anymore (not by name and not at scope [probably]),

1. does anyone have a solution / idea / direction ?
2. does anyone have info on the CPS Transform process (specifically to Jenkins, not the CPS theory), or how can i see the end product WorkflowScript after the transformation ?

Comment: the error `No such property: stringUtil` but there is no such property anywhere in your code sample. mistype?

Comment: sorry, i have changed my packages and classes so the example would be simple to understand, unfortunately i forgot the stack-trace, i will change it accordingly - thanks for the remark

Comment: i believe, if you call from `node(){ ... }` the method `closure()` directly without library - you'll get the same error - right?

Comment: you are correct, still my question remains the same, why the 'closure' function can't see the var ? if i try to call:  `echo "tester: " + tester`  from the node it works fine

Comment: It's a basic of groovy script. Plain variables are local to script itself. And script during compilation appeares as a content of method `run()`. So, it's like you want to access from method `closure()` the variable declared inside method `run()`

Comment: I don't have pipeline under hands to test, but try to declare  `tester` without type and access level. In this case it should be created as a binding of script. `tester = new Tester(this)`

Comment: i already tried to define without public and without Tester (`def tester = new Tester(this)`) and it did not work, but i haven't tried without def (`tester = new Tester(this)`) - that worked, thanks allot for your time, could you please set it as an answer and i can mark it for others ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on [daggett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1276664/daggett) solution in the remarks:

1. jenkins pipeline scripted job is written in groovy
2. it is then compiled and CPS transformed (during runrime) into a WorkflowScript groovy class with a single method that is executed

and since it is just a groovy class then the groovy scoping rules should apply,
in groovy if you declare a var / 'def' you can do it without the 'def' prefix and that would declare it globally available everywhere in the script,

so change the declaration in the pipeline script to this:

```
tester = new Tester(this)
```

and that's it!

> **Jenkins pipeline script:**

```
@Library("testLib") _

import my.domain.Tester;

// note the definition without the 'def' or Tester or public
tester = new Tester(this);

def closure()
{
    echo "tester: " + tester;
}

node("master")
{
    tester.test();
}
```

**OR:**

since Groovy version 1.8 and up, we can add the @Field annotation and keep the declaration as it is,

[how-do-i-create-and-access-the-global-variables-in-groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305910/how-do-i-create-and-access-the-global-variables-in-groovy)

so we can also change the pipeline to look like this:

> **Jenkins pipeline script:**

```
@Library("testLib") _

import my.domain.Tester;

// note the definition without the 'def' or Tester or public
@Field Tester tester = new Tester(this);

def closure()
{
    echo "tester: " + tester;
}

node("master")
{
    tester.test();
}
```

Comment: please read: https://blogs.sap.com/2017/06/22/avoid-binding-variables-in-groovy-scripts to understand binding fields without the def definition and understand the risks and behaviors