# Groovy variable cannot be accessed within the function

Tags: groovy

```
/* Hello World in Groovy */
println("Hello world")


int a =  5



if (1 == 1){
    println a
    fcn() //line 11
}

def fcn(){
    println a //line 15
}
```

This is my Groovy script, which gets the error

```
Hello world
5
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: a for class: main
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: a for class: main
    at main.fcn(main.groovy:15)
    at main.run(main.groovy:11)
```

when executed. Why the variable `a` is not available within the function `fcn`?

Answer (score 1):

You can define variable `a` differently:

Option 1

```
a = 5
```

Option 2

```
import groovy.transform.Field

...
@Field int a = 5
```

The rational is to define a field in a scope of the script as opposed to the variable defined in the "run method" of the Script and hence not accessible from within other functions.

Consider checking [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305910/how-do-i-create-and-access-the-global-variables-in-groovy) for more information
A link to [Field](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/Field.html) annotation document also provides relevant information

Answer (score 1):

Option 3
You can define the `fcn` as a proper function, which is in Groovy represented by `Closure`.
Then you can access the variables of outer scope:

```
int a =  5

def fcn = {     
  println a
}

if(true){
  fcn()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try `a = 5` while defining the global variable this should be available in the function fcn.

[How do I create and access the global variables in Groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305910/how-do-i-create-and-access-the-global-variables-in-groovy)