# Groovy no signature of method

Tags: function, class, methods, groovy

I am trying to create a function in `Groovy` that inputs a string and returns a modified string. The problem I believe is within an addon, which is a specific software environment I am working with i.e. `logic.script.Microblock`. The error message I am receiving is:

```
No signature of method: com.controlj.addonsupport.logic.script.Microblock.capAbbreviate() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [OAT Dewpoint bavo].
```

I have tried `dispName = capAbbreviate(dispName.toString())`, `dispName = capAbbreviate(dispName)`, and `capAbbreviate(dispName)`.

The software environment is using some sort of addon. I am still fairly new to Groovy/Java so this seems like it could be something simple but it's not clicking in my head just yet.

The code simplified below is:

```
def exceptions = ['Ac':'AC','Oat':'OAT','Vav':'VAV']
def exceptionNonAlpha = '(?=[^a-zA-Z])'
def dispName

def capAbbreviate(String mbText)
{
    // Iterates through 'exceptions' map and finds abbreviations and recapitalizes them
    for (hvacName in exceptions.keySet()) {
        mbText = mbText.replaceAll(hvacName + exceptionNonAlpha, exceptions[hvacName])
    }
    return mbText
}

logic.microblocks
{
    dispName = prop.'display name'
    dispName = capAbbreviate(dispName.toString()) // also tried capAbbreviate(dispName)
    println dispName
}
```

Comment: Your code is not really correct and not enough to reproduce the problem. 1. You have problems with using `exceptions` and `exceptionNonAlpha` script variables inside the function. 2. How do you define `logic` variable? 3. What is `com.controlj.addonsupport.logic.script.Microblock`? Is it your class or a class from some library? 4. The code above - is it script or is it a part of some class? Could you please update your question considering these points?

Comment: As a half-blind guess I may say that you just change `def capAbbreviate(String mbText)` definition to `static def capAbbreviate(String mbText)`, but I'm not sure it'll help much. Would be nice if you could update your question with additional information. I see that something is wrong with the scope of your method that you call from the closure.

Comment: @AndrejIstomin I updated the original problem but the `com.controlj.addonsupport.logic.script.Microblock` is the software environment I am working in that automatically loads that addon.

I did try adding in `static def` but came back with this error:
`org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 158: Apparent variable 'exceptions' was found in a static scope but doesn't refer to a local variable, static field or class.`

Comment: try to declare `exceptions` variable as `exceptions = ['Ac':'AC','Oat':'OAT','Vav':'VAV']` instead of `exceptions = ['Ac':'AC','Oat':'OAT','Vav':'VAV']` (the same for `exceptionNonAlpha`), it will make those variables global.

Comment: @AndrejIstomin I'm guessing you mean `**def** exceptions = ['Ac':'AC','Oat':'OAT','Vav':'VAV']` to `exceptions = ['Ac':'AC','Oat':'OAT','Vav':'VAV']`. I'm trying to determine how to make `dispName` global as well because that might be part of the problem.

Comment: Yes, I meant just delete `def`, that's how you make the variable "global". See the explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305910/how-do-i-create-and-access-the-global-variables-in-groovy

Comment: Thanks @AndrejIstomin, that solved part of the issue. I was able to do trial and error and found that `this.` before the method resolved the issue. I can finally rest in peace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution has two parts:

Similar to what @AndrejIstomin mentioned, removing the `def` to make a list or variable global resolved one part of the issue

The second part to the solution is that `this.` needed to be used to call the method. i.e. `this.capAbbreviate(dispName)`